# xcode 3.2.6 and iOS 4.3 SDK installation problem on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-lion

I recently brought a new Mac mini running Max OSX 10.7(Lion)

I downloaded the iOS SDK 4.3 and Xcode 3.2.6.dmg from [here](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=20792)

The download is successful and i was able to install it without any problem.
But after INSTALLING I CANNOT FIND XCODE IN /DEVELOPER/APPLICATIONS folder.

In /DEVELOPER/APPLICATIONS folder i only find

**performance tools and utilities** folders.
Can anybody help me in properly installing xcode on Lion?

Comment: Is there some reason why you are not using Xcode 4.2 ?

Comment: after some googling i found that xcode 4 is little buggy and also i saw xcode 4.2 is a paid developer version in developer.apple.com.

Comment: you could use 4.1 there is nothing wrong with it and I have a feeling its free now.

Comment: Why are you yelling at us? You are the one using old version which is not ready for Lion. 4.2 is still in private developer beta, but 4.1 which you can download for free from AppStore is perfectly fine :) Also, this is not really a programming question, so it would be a better fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or even [Apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) Q&A sites.

Comment: Thanks gemiCoder and ficheck for the response.I am thinking of shifting to Xcode 4.1.But the problem is i even cannot uninstall the sdk using the standard command

Comment: @ficheck  I posted the same question in Apple Q &A site u pointed.If i have no other way i will go to xcode 4.1

Comment: But Xcode4.1 Build:4B103 with iOS 4.3 is buggy. Read below threads for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670229/exe-bad-access-in-line-14-in-main-m-after-i-type-randomly-when-program-launches and this thread https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit/issues/75#issuecomment-2343312

Answer (score 3):

mount xcode326.dmg, open terminal, type following 2 commands:

```
export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1
open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"
```

xcode should install successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I already installed Xcode 4.1 and it is working fine.